# Nested iframes not sizing correctly

Tags: iframe-resizer

The height of the iframe is too high when using nested iframes.

See the following URL:
http://champion.fme-cat.com/outer.htm

Click on the drop-down list and notice the height is too high.

Now when you scroll down the list of options the height shrinks until finally when you get to the last option in the list, the height is correct.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you drop down is bigger than the page it is in. The dropdown can not work out side of the iFrame, so the frame grows to prevent it being chop short.